# Exercise applying Leftover hash Lemma

Tags: hash, entropy, universal-hash

Say that X is a (k; n)-source if $X\in\{0,1\}^2$, and the min-entropy of X is at least k.
Answer the following questions:

(i) Suppose that $l=128$; what is the minimal amount of min-entropy needed
in order to obtain statistical error $\epsilon=2^{-80}$ when applying the leftover hash lemma? What is the entropy loss?

(ii) Suppose that $k = 238$; what is the maximal amount of uniform randomness that you can obtain with statistical error $\epsilon= 2^{-80}$ when applying the leftover hash lemma? Explain how to obtain $l= 320$ using computational assumptions.

I tried to solve this problem applying the LHL, but I'm not so sure.
For the first problem I used that $l=k-2log(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$, so I found $k=288$. But for the other questions I have no idea.

Comment: The Lemma is easier than you think.  Find the formula and shove it up Wolfram Alpha.